# Database structure and architecture for analytical data to present in UI

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, database

I need some advice or reassurance...

We are working on an web based application (ASP.NET) on hotel analytics. The Page has different sections that show different charts for specific hotel locations(Total Sales, Room Turnovers etc)for the night before and past history

This data can be run in a nightly job (stored proc) to populate the tables since the data doesnt have to be current. Yesterday data is what is needed not real time. Should each analytic section in the page have the data come from a specific table in the database that is populated by that stored proc (the stored proc will initially get info from multiple tables it needs)? Or is it better for each analytic section have its own table for isolation purposes? For example, all data about Total Sales should be in one table and turnover info on another table.

Im debating and going towards each having its own table since the data is somewhat different. Having all data in one table means there will be a lot of cells with nulls on them. But then again, as new analytics requirement come in, that means adding more tables..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this is called NORMALIZATION of your data structure.

you do NOT want one big table with everything in it (including a bunch of nulls)

you DO want to have one table per main logical concept, and then some more to link them logically together.

if you want more specific ideas on how to split things - then edit your question with some columns you think you want to store - as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the analysis from the interface.  The key here is the "entity".  Measures on the same entity should be in the same table.  So, you should put all information about hotel locations into the same table.

What you will have are sets of columns related to each other.  For instance, all the columns related to hotel occupancy might be one group and another group might be sales.  I would suggest prefixing these columns to identify their themes.  Something like "occ_" for occupancy and "sales_" for sales.

I would suggest structuring these so each theme is in its own stored procedure.  If possible, I would use well-name views to create the information to add into the big table.

You may have other information at other levels, such as geography.  This information would be in a different table.

This might get a big more complicated if you want drill-through capability.  But, you didn't ask about that.

One important thing to remember.  As you start designing the application, you may have very clear demarkations between different columns.  However, users will start to blur the lines and bring different elements together.  After all, that is the power of analytics and data visualization.